# Declaring lots of TkInter Intvar control variables in Python

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I need more than 25 radiobutton groups in my window.

For getting their values I need control variables.

To declare them I did this:

var1=Intvar()

var2=Intvar()

var3=Intvar()

.

.

var25=Intvar()

Is there any simpler, more compact way to declare (like an array or similar in C) and work with them than this?

Answer (score 1):

If these radiobuttons are all part of a group, you only need one IntVar. If they are all distinct, a radiobutton is the wrong choice.  Radiobuttons are designed to share one variable between all related instances.

Regardless, instances of `IntVar` are no different than any other object in python - strings, integers, numbers, etc.

```
vars = []
for i in range(25):
    vars.append(IntVar())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I wanted.